# SQL insert columns from one procedure to another

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, exec, procedure

I have a stored procedure that returns many columns and is very cumbersome to work with, I created another stored procedure that converts rows to columns. How do I insert the columns from the sub procedure into the main procedure?

I am think that were I want to put the columns from the sub procedure I code it like:

```
(select * from subprocedure where X= 1) as subquerycolumns
```

is this correct?

Here is my Table Function, however I am receiving a "The column prefix 'IPAM_RIPS_SKILL-SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_HDR" does not match with a table name or alias..." error, Everything looks fine to me though, can someone help me.

```
CREATE FUNCTION PARTICIPANTRATINGSET
(@PARTICIPANT_ID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT 
        ST1.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET1, SS1.SET_NAME AS NAME1, ST1.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R1,
        ST2.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET2, SS2.SET_NAME AS NAME2, ST2.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R2,
        ST3.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET3, SS3.SET_NAME AS NAME3, ST3.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R3,
        ST4.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET4, SS4.SET_NAME AS NAME4, ST4.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R4,
        ST5.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET5, ST5.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL AS NAME5, ST5.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R5,
        ST6.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET6, ST6.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL AS NAME6, ST6.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R6,
        ST7.SKILL_SET_ID AS SET7, ST7.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL AS NAME7, ST7.SKILL_SET_RATING AS R7,
        CM.COMMENTS
    FROM IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_HDR HT
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST1
        ON HT.ID = ST1.HDR_ID and st1.SKILL_SET_ID = 1
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS1
        ON ST1.SKILL_SET_ID = SS1.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST2
        ON HT.ID = ST2.HDR_ID and st2.SKILL_SET_ID = 2
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS2
        ON ST2.SKILL_SET_ID = SS2.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST3
        ON HT.ID = ST3.HDR_ID and st3.SKILL_SET_ID = 3
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS3
        ON ST3.SKILL_SET_ID = SS3.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST4
        ON HT.ID = ST4.HDR_ID and st4.SKILL_SET_ID = 4
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS4
        ON ST4.SKILL_SET_ID = SS4.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST5
        ON HT.ID = ST5.HDR_ID and st5.SKILL_SET_ID = 5
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS5
        ON ST5.SKILL_SET_ID = SS5.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST6
        ON HT.ID = ST6.HDR_ID and st6.SKILL_SET_ID = 10
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS6
        ON ST6.SKILL_SET_ID = SS6.ID
    LEFT JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL ST7
        ON HT.ID = ST7.HDR_ID and st7.SKILL_SET_ID = 11
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SETS SS7
        ON ST7.SKILL_SET_ID = SS7.ID
    INNER JOIN IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_COMMENTS CM
        ON HT.ID = CM.HDR_ID
    WHERE IPAM_RIPS_SKILL_SET_PARTICIPANT_RATING_HDR.PARTICIPANT_ID = @PARTICIPANT_ID
    GROUP BY PARTICIPANT_ID, ST1.SKILL_SET_ID, SS1.SET_NAME, ST1.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST2.SKILL_SET_ID, SS2.SET_NAME, ST2.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST3.SKILL_SET_ID, SS3.SET_NAME, ST3.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST4.SKILL_SET_ID, SS4.SET_NAME, ST4.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST5.SKILL_SET_ID, ST5.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL, ST5.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST6.SKILL_SET_ID, ST6.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL, ST6.SKILL_SET_RATING, ST7.SKILL_SET_ID, ST7.SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL, ST7.SKILL_SET_RATING, CM.COMMENTS
GO
```

Comment: `Show uz teh codez`. (please)

Comment: what the hell is 'uz' and 'codez'? And te code is unimportant, the has to be a general answer without seeing code, I'm assuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table function did not work and was causing too many issue.  I went with a view instead which worked jsut as good

Answer (score 1):

You you can't use procedures in that way, you need to use [table functions](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions) for using the results in queries like a table or view.

Comment: you can call a procedure from another procedure,but you can't use the result set (even if it's one row) and put that single row results into the existing select query?

Comment: Yes, that is, that's the reason why they created table functions. Note that stored procedures can return *several* sets of data, from the docs: "[stored prodecures return] A result set for each SELECT statement contained in the stored procedure or any other stored procedures called by the stored procedure." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28SQL.80%29.aspx). I suppose that this is one of the reasons that beginning with SQL Server 2005 the database offer access to metadata using table functions instead of procedures (so you can combine and filter the resulting data).

Answer (score 0):

OPENROWSET into a temp table, from which you can do your insert.

From [this link](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=82388):

```
use tempdb
go

select
    a.*
into
    MyTemp
from
    openrowset('SQLOLEDB','SERVER=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    '
    SET FMTONLY OFF;
    EXEC SP_HELPDB
    ') a

INSERT INTO MyTable (a, b, c)
select a, b, c from MyTemp

drop table MyTemp
```

Comment: how is this going to inser columns from one procedure into another? This is a select query

Comment: That should be used only as a last resort method if for some reason you can't convert the procedure to a table function, since it opens *another connection* to the database, and you have to enable remote connections just for this (OPENROWSET and OPENDATAQUERY are disabled by default starting with SQL Server 2005).

Comment: @mattgcon - thanks, i'd meant to edit the example before wandering off to get coffee.

Comment: @Alberto - thanks, table functions in 2005 is the way to go.  +1

Comment: @LesterDove - and also in SQL Server 2000 (that was the first version that implemented them). The only gotcha is that the result set is not indexed, so it could generate slow queries when used in `JOIN`.

Comment: How do I reference the table function columns within a select statement